# How to remove this Top Space in the Background Image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a simple HTML code to set a background image to my webpage, but still it shows me a free space in the top of the Page, I tried to life the Background image with this code, It was lifted to the up, Can you confirm me, is it the proper way or are there any issue with my existing CSS codes?

```
margin-top:-20px
```

My CSS Code,

```
<style>
.bg-image {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%;
  background-image: url("/bg.jpg");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
```

My HTML Code :

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Body part will invoke the inner divisions, So make sure about the Body Margins, If we set body `margin:0px; padding:0px;` then that will touch the top of the browser.

Try this code inside your CSS Code,

```
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```